# How to properly omit NAs from a nested list?

Tags: r

I'm working with a list of lists - let's call it `L` - in R, where the sub-lists are all the same length & padded with NAs. Ideally, I'd like to remove just the NA elements from each sublist, and one solution I've come up with is `L <- lapply(L, na.omit)`. It seems to *almost* work; however, for each sub-list, the behavior is such that, for example,

```
[[1]]
[1] "0"     "12345"  "12346"  "12347" "12348"  "12349"  "12340"  "12341"  "12342" NA      NA          NA      NA      NA      NA     

[16] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

becomes

```
[[1]]
[1] "0"     "12345"  "12346"  "12347" "12348"  "12349"  "12340"  "12341"  "12342"
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

I'm a little bemused, to be honest - what's up with the extra `attr()`s and such in my list?  Is there a solution out there that won't append them to the list? I've tried `na.exclude`, but it gives the same result. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No reason to be bemused... the Details section of `?na.omit` says:

> If ‘na.omit’ removes cases, the row numbers of the cases form the
>   ‘"na.action"’ attribute of the result, of class ‘"omit"’.

Try subsetting each list element with `is.na`:

```
L <- lapply(L, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using higher order functions

```
lapply(L, Filter, f = Negate(is.na))
```